# Coefficient of function with general argument

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I would like to obtain the coefficients of a general function f in a list. For example, the coefficient list of

```
testList = {{2 f[2] + 3 f[3]},{2 f[1]}, {Sqrt[2] f[4]}}
```

should be the list

```
{{2,3},{2},{Sqrt[2]}}
```

I've tried the obvious solution

```
CoefficientList[testList, Variables[testList]]
```

But this gives me a lot of extra information, plus requires a few more array operations to write it in the correct form. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this, since my lists will be eventually very large?

Answer (score 3):

[Cases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) can be used to extract a value that's part of a pattern:

```
Cases[#, x_ f[_] -> x, Infinity] & /@ testList
```

Out:

```
{{2, 3}, {2}, {Sqrt[2]}}
```

Comment: Since the variable names could change: `Cases[#, x_ Alternatives @@ Variables[testList] -> x, Infinity] & /@ testList`